# About the names of groups

Tags: python, regex

Is it risky to uses such kind of pattern `(?P<gp1>...(?P<subgpA>...)...)|(?P<gp2>...(?P<subgpA>...)...)` where I use the same name for subgroups in different first level groups in an alternative ?

For the names of the first level groups, they would be all different.

Comment: Yes. Try before ask. A good philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much risky as impossible.  Try using that code in a pattern.

> sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'subgpA' as group 4; was group 2